# generate phpexcel output based on id

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I want to export a data from database into an excel file. i've tried to use PHPExcel

im trying to get some data with `id` as the parameter with this code, but the result of the export is showing all data. meanwhile, when i do the `var_dump` at the '$rowExcel->name', its showing a data based on id (not all data).

```
$this->db->select('id, name, r_value');
$this->db->where_in('id', $id);
$result = $this->db->get("person");
$rows = 3;
foreach ($result->result() as $rowExcel){
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0,$rows,'');
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1,$rows,$rowExcel->name);
    $rows++;
}
```

what i want is to export the data with the id as the parameter (not export all data).. btw, the id is an array

Comment: you didn't tell us - what exactly your problem is - as far as i can tell - your code looks _somewhat_ fine... (ps: is there a  reason for you to choose `PHPExcel` over `PHPSpreadsheet`? The development of PHPExcel stopped 4 years ago.)

Comment: my reason for choosing `PHPExcel` is just because my PHP version is to old.. im using the 5.4,, 

btw, the problem is solved.it was just my browser didnt perform well because i have uncleared cache. thanks

Comment: Glad it's solved but you seriously need to move to a new version of PHP. Version 7.4 starts beta testing tomorrow (25 July).